# .toggle is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my website I have a lot of buttons. When the page loads, I need the first button to be clicked.

I tried getting the first button and then using the function .toggle('click').

var $btn = $('.btn-personalizar-tamanho')[0];
if($btn != undefined) $btn.toggle('click');

The console says .toggle it's not a function.

Comment: err, what does toggle have to do with clicking the first button?

Comment: toggle() is not clicking the element....

Comment: Meant to close as duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: $(…)\[index\].hide/show is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38810941/215552) but clicked the wrong button...

Comment: @HereticMonkey that is one of many issues with the code.

Comment: @KevinB that is only one of the issues...

Comment: @epascarello You are correct. The duplicate answers the title "question". If the OP has additional questions after fixing that one, they are welcome and encouraged to ask another question about any further issues with their code.

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
document.querySelector(selector).classList.toggle('classname');
```

Answer (score 0):

The [0] returns a single DOM element from the jQuery collection. Remove it.

Use the jQuery result directly, fill-in as appropriate. eg:

```
$(selector).toggle()
```

(Note that toggle belongs to the jQuery object itself.)

There is no need to check for existence of elements. The selector will have to be adapted for “first” as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

First `[0]` returns the DOM element and a DOM element does not have a toggle method hence why you are getting the error message. Second, [jQuery's `toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) shows and hides an element, that is not triggering the click event.

If you want to trigger the click event then you use `click()` or `trigger('click')`. to get the first element you can use [`first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) or `:first` or `eq(0)` to get the element.

```
$('.btn-personalizar-tamanho').first().click()
```

or

```
$('.btn-personalizar-tamanho').first().trigger('click')
```

There is also no need to check if the element exists with jQuery because it does it under the hood when you chain methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this if the button exists it will click it.

```
$('.btn-personalizar-tamanho').click();
```

If you need the first item specifically then add the "first" method

```
$('.btn-personalizar-tamanho').first().click();
```

also your solution will work if you wrap the result in another jquery selector and change the toggle method to trigger

```
$btn = $('.btn-personalizar-tamanho')[0];
if($btn != undefined) $($btn).trigger('click');
```